# Compile VLCKit under OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Tags: xcode, macos, vlc, osx-yosemite, libvlc

I have been trying for days to compile VLCKit under my OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), Macbook Pro Retina 64bit environment, XCode 6.1

I tried to follow all these guides:

- https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/ (tried to follow the steps from "Building the framework for OS X". Dozens of errors in XCode
- https://metakermit.com/2010/how-to-set-up-vlckit-in-os-x/
- [Compile VLCKit on Mac OS 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123399/compile-vlckit-on-mac-os-10-9)

Especially the last one really looked like it could work. I followed all the steps, but the

```
xcodebuild -project VLCKit.xcodeproj -verbose -target "Make VLC" -configuration Release
```

command will just fail with

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution make build/VLCKit.build/Release/Make\ VLC.build/Script-6337548010ED091D0072A0D9.sh
(1 failure)
```

This is slowly driving me crazy. What should I do to make VLCKit work under my environment?

Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: you should post the contents of the "run scripts" build phases along with the build output from before the error.

Comment: Just to be sure here are the logs of every single step I took:
 - http://pastebin.com/pBe5ySX4 (Fetch libvlc)
 - (Set VLC contribs was just HUGE, but if needed I can post it somewhere)
 - http://pastebin.com/qTaWTW57 (bootstrap)
 - http://pastebin.com/5nzkdCG9 (run VLC configure)
 - http://pastebin.com/B4JxUA1S (make VLC)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a lot of the same issues as you.

Start afresh and follow this guy's solution;

[Compile VLCKit on Mac OS 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123399/compile-vlckit-on-mac-os-10-9)

only replacing os x (which was set at 10.6 in 3 places) with by 10.9 in the pbxproj of VLCKit.xcodeproj (aka , show package contents), I am not sure if this step is necessary.

Then I was having issues at 'Make VLC' at this point, my error was related to looking for clang 4.2 in XCode, but these days we have clang 6.0;  I found that by disabling x265 I was able to compile in the end; aka

Add `args="--disable-x265 $args"` to the Configure.sh in VLCKit folder.

GL, Let me know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to build VLCKit under Yosemite. The guide you posted did work for me, but there was one additional problem I figured out and that made it work.

The first target "Fetch libvlc" always failed to clone the git repository and so the rest of the process failed. You have to clone it manually to make it work. "Fetch libvlc" will succeed when the folder already exists.

So here are the steps I followed:

- Checkout VLCKit
- inside the VLCKit directory, `git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc.git`
- rename the created "vlc" folder to "vlc-unstable"
- follow the steps in the guide in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25139964/2595970) after "Cloning Project"

Two notes:

- I didn't have to replace NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER, it seems like they fixed it since the guide was posted
- Like others noted, I had to add `args="--disable-x265 $args"` to the "Configure.sh" script or the build would fail

By following these steps I was able to build VLCKit, I hope this works for others as well, as I struggled a lot with it like many others.

Comment: I followed your steps but get an error after the `Run VLC configure` phase: `The following build commands failed: PhaseScriptExecution configure build/VLCKit.build/Release/Run\ VLC\ configure.build/Script-63FFDBCD0D2AE2AE0092FC96.sh`

Comment: Hey @devian, make sure you add `args="--disable-x265 $args"` to "Configure.sh" without any spelling errors. I just tried it with the last `"` character missing and got the same error message, so I guess you have a mistake in "Configure.sh". Hope that helps.

Comment: You're config seems fine, it ran through when I tested it. So I guess problem comes from one of the earlier steps...