# Use VLCKit in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, compilation, libvlc

I try to use VLCKit for an OS X Project coded in Swift, so I built the Framework thanks to [compile vlckit on mac os 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123399/compile-vlckit-on-mac-os-10-9).
Then, I inserted the generated VLCKit.Framework in my project (I see it in the linked Frameworks and Libraries) but when I want to use it or just compile my project with, I have an issue :

```
ld: framework not found VLCKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So, I don't understand how to make it works....

Thanks for your help !

EDIT :
I also tried on a Objective-C project, It does the same error..

EDIT 2 : I get a VLCKit.framework from Internet, and the compilation of my project works. It's my own compilation of the framework that didn't work..

Anyway, 
I can use the framework on a Objective-C project, but the "import VLCKit" in a Swift file didn't work : "No such module 'VLCKit'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## To deploy VLCKit in your swift project, follow these steps :

- Install the sdk (e.g., using cocoapods)
- Link the required dependencies (mentioned in the framework repository)
- Create a bridging header (VLCKit is written in objective c)

#### The process of installing and using the sdk is well-explained in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmdSnCw-Mjw)

Good luck

Comment: Could you please help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70313743/how-do-i-install-vlckit-in-ios?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the framework location to your framework / library search paths. Xcode can't find it.

Comment: Well, The framework is in the project folder, and it is this folder indicated for Framework Search Paths and Library Search Paths...