# CompileC XCode Build of VLCKit fails

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, compiler-errors, vlc

So I have been following [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123399/compile-vlckit-on-mac-os-10-9) right until the end. When I try to execute the second last step:

```
xcodebuild -project VLCKit.xcodeproj -verbose -target "Build just VLCKit" -configuration Release
```

I get:

> The following build commands failed:
>       CompileC build/VLCKit.build/Release/Build\ just\ VLCKit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/VLCMediaPlayer.o Sources/VLCMediaPlayer.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (1 failure)

What could this be? I have found some answers, but nothing of much use (most of the problems posted concern problems at a much earlier build stage) and almost everything regards iOS / MobileVLC. I am looking to use VLCKit on OSX however.

Edit: In response to the first comment, this might be a more accurate error message:

> /Users/.../VLCKit/Sources/VLCMediaPlayer.m:794:60: error: no member named 'b_menu' in
>         'struct libvlc_title_description_t'
>                                              @(titleInfo[i]->b_menu),
>                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^

If this doesn't help, let me know where to look for the proper error message.

Comment: There should be a more detailed error message, earlier in the output.

Comment: i have updated the description. any idea?