# VLCKit for ios failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, libvlc

I'm trying to install VLCKit for iOS by following [this](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/#Compilation_tips). It says that after downloading the [project](http://%20http://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit.git), install vlc framework for iOS is by  executing **./buildMobileVLCKit.sh -f** in terminal.

I obtain this at the end of log :

```
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libass.a(ass_fontconfig.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libass.a(utils.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libass.a(ass_fontconfig.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libass.a(utils.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/iPhone-i386-apple-darwin11-i386/lib/libass.a(ass_fontconfig.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/iPhone-i386-apple-darwin11-i386/lib/libass.a(utils.o) has no symbols
libavcodec/audiotoolboxdec.c:344:34: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'UInt32 *'
      (aka 'unsigned long *') to parameter of type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                                 &in_format.mChannelsPerFrame, &avctx->frame_size,
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/mpegaudiodecheader.h:58:31: note: passing argument to parameter 'channels' here
                         int *channels, int *frame_size, int *bitrate, enum AVCodecID *codec_id);
                              ^
libavcodec/audiotoolboxdec.c:548:43: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int *' to parameter of type
      'UInt32 * _Nonnull' (aka 'unsigned long *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                                          &frame->nb_samples, &out_buffers, NULL);
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Headers/AudioConverter.h:828:73: note: 
      passing argument to parameter 'ioOutputDataPacketSize' here
                                    UInt32 *                            ioOutputDataPacketSize,
                                                                        ^
libavcodec/audiotoolboxdec.c:559:61: warning: values of type 'OSStatus' should not be used as format arguments;
      add an explicit cast to 'int' instead [-Wformat]
        av_log(avctx, AV_LOG_WARNING, "Decode error: %i\n", ret);
                                                     ~~     ^~~
                                                            (int)
libavcodec/avrndec.c:110:15: warning: 'avcodec_decode_video2' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(a->mjpeg_avctx, data, got_frame, avpkt);
              ^
libavcodec/avcodec.h:4763:5: note: 'avcodec_decode_video2' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int avcodec_decode_video2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *picture,
    ^
1 warning generated.
3 warnings generated.
libavcodec/bitstream_filter.c:40:12: warning: returning 'const AVBitStreamFilter *' (aka
      'const struct AVBitStreamFilter *') from a function with result type 'AVBitStreamFilter *'
      (aka 'struct AVBitStreamFilter *') discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    return av_bsf_next(&opaque);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/bitstream_filter.c:71:20: warning: assigning to 'struct AVBitStreamFilter *' from
      'const AVBitStreamFilter *' (aka 'const struct AVBitStreamFilter *') discards qualifiers
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    ctx->filter    = bsf;
                   ^ ~~~
libavcodec/bitstream_filter.c:133:14: warning: assigning to 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') from
      'const uint8_t *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') discards qualifiers
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    pkt.data = buf;
             ^ ~~~
3 warnings generated.
libavcodec/g726.c:157:23: warning: unused function 'quant' [-Wunused-function]
static inline uint8_t quant(G726Context* c, int d)
                      ^
1 warning generated.
libavcodec/h264_refs.c:371:13: warning: variable 'i' is used uninitialized whenever switch default is taken
      [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
            default:
            ^~~~~~~
libavcodec/h264_refs.c:375:17: note: uninitialized use occurs here
            if (i < 0) {
                ^
libavcodec/h264_refs.c:314:18: note: initialize the variable 'i' to silence this warning
            int i;
                 ^
                  = 0
1 warning generated.
libavcodec/mpegvideo_enc.c:1400:11: warning: 'avcodec_encode_video2' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
          ^
libavcodec/avcodec.h:5271:5: note: 'avcodec_encode_video2' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int avcodec_encode_video2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVPacket *avpkt,
    ^
libavcodec/mpegvideo_enc.c:2868:31: warning: variable 'pred_x' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    bytestream_put_byte(&ptr, pred_x); /* hmv1 */
                              ^~~~~~
libavcodec/mpegvideo_enc.c:2861:15: note: initialize the variable 'pred_x' to silence this warning
    int pred_x, pred_y;
              ^
               = 0
libavcodec/mpegvideo_enc.c:2869:31: warning: variable 'pred_y' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    bytestream_put_byte(&ptr, pred_y); /* vmv1 */
                              ^~~~~~
libavcodec/mpegvideo_enc.c:2861:23: note: initialize the variable 'pred_y' to silence this warning
    int pred_x, pred_y;
                      ^
                       = 0
libavcodec/pcm.c:34:20: warning: unused function 'pcm_encode_init' [-Wunused-function]
static av_cold int pcm_encode_init(AVCodecContext *avctx)
                   ^
libavcodec/pcm.c:83:12: warning: unused function 'pcm_encode_frame' [-Wunused-function]
static int pcm_encode_frame(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVPacket *avpkt,
           ^
2 warnings generated.
3 warnings generated.
libavcodec/smvjpegdec.c:158:15: warning: 'avcodec_decode_video2' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(s->avctx, mjpeg_data, &s->mjpeg_data_size, avpkt);
              ^
libavcodec/avcodec.h:4763:5: note: 'avcodec_decode_video2' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int avcodec_decode_video2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *picture,
    ^
1 warning generated.
libavcodec/sonic.c:160:19: warning: unused function 'intlist_write' [-Wunused-function]
static inline int intlist_write(RangeCoder *c, uint8_t *state, int *buf, int entries, int base_2_part)
                  ^
1 warning generated.
libavcodec/svq3.c:618:29: warning: unused function 'dctcoef_get' [-Wunused-function]
static av_always_inline int dctcoef_get(int16_t *mb, int index)
                            ^
libavcodec/tdsc.c:354:11: warning: 'avcodec_decode_video2' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ret = avcodec_decode_video2(ctx->jpeg_avctx, ctx->jpgframe,
          ^
libavcodec/avcodec.h:4763:5: note: 'avcodec_decode_video2' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int avcodec_decode_video2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *picture,
    ^
1 warning generated.
1 warning generated.
libavcodec/utils.c:2205:26: warning: assigning to 'AVPacket *' (aka 'struct AVPacket *') from 'const AVPacket *'
      (aka 'const struct AVPacket *') discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    avctx->internal->pkt = avpkt;
                         ^ ~~~~~
libavcodec/utils.c:2206:37: warning: passing 'const AVPacket *' (aka 'const struct AVPacket *') to parameter of
      type 'AVPacket *' (aka 'struct AVPacket *') discards qualifiers
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    ret = apply_param_change(avctx, avpkt);
                                    ^~~~~
libavcodec/utils.c:2056:64: note: passing argument to parameter 'avpkt' here
static int apply_param_change(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVPacket *avpkt)
                                                               ^
libavcodec/utils.c:2734:15: warning: 'avcodec_decode_video2' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(avctx, avctx->internal->buffer_frame,
              ^
libavcodec/utils.c:2180:25: note: 'avcodec_decode_video2' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int attribute_align_arg avcodec_decode_video2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *picture,
                        ^
libavcodec/utils.c:2739:15: warning: 'avcodec_decode_audio4' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ret = avcodec_decode_audio4(avctx, avctx->internal->buffer_frame,
              ^
libavcodec/utils.c:2281:25: note: 'avcodec_decode_audio4' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int attribute_align_arg avcodec_decode_audio4(AVCodecContext *avctx,
                        ^
libavcodec/utils.c:2875:15: warning: 'avcodec_encode_video2' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ret = avcodec_encode_video2(avctx, avctx->internal->buffer_pkt,
              ^
libavcodec/utils.c:1922:25: note: 'avcodec_encode_video2' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int attribute_align_arg avcodec_encode_video2(AVCodecContext *avctx,
                        ^
libavcodec/utils.c:2878:15: warning: 'avcodec_encode_audio2' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(avctx, avctx->internal->buffer_pkt,
              ^
libavcodec/utils.c:1776:25: note: 'avcodec_encode_audio2' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int attribute_align_arg avcodec_encode_audio2(AVCodecContext *avctx,
                        ^
6 warnings generated.
libavcodec/x86/h264_qpel.c:388:1: warning: unused function 'ff_avg_h264_qpel8or16_hv1_lowpass_mmxext'
      [-Wunused-function]
QPEL_H264(avg_, AVG_MMXEXT_OP, mmxext)
^
libavcodec/x86/h264_qpel.c:94:30: note: expanded from macro 'QPEL_H264'
static av_always_inline void ff_ ## OPNAME ## h264_qpel8or16_hv1_lowpass_ ## MMX(int16_t *tmp, const uint8...
                             ^
<scratch space>:47:1: note: expanded from here
ff_avg_h264_qpel8or16_hv1_lowpass_mmxext
^
1 warning generated.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip: input object file stripped: /Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/iPhoneSimulator-i386/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/proresdsp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip: input object file stripped: /Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/iPhoneSimulator-i386/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/simple_idct10.o
libswscale/input.c:944:1: warning: unused function 'planar_rgb9le_to_a' [-Wunused-function]
rgb9plus_planar_funcs(9)
^
libswscale/input.c:941:5: note: expanded from macro 'rgb9plus_planar_funcs'
    rgb9plus_planar_funcs_endian(nbits, le, 0)  \
    ^
libswscale/input.c:929:13: note: expanded from macro 'rgb9plus_planar_funcs_endian'
static void planar_rgb##nbits##endian_name##_to_a(uint8_t *dst, const uint8_t *src[4],              \
            ^
<scratch space>:161:1: note: expanded from here
planar_rgb9le_to_a
^
libswscale/input.c:944:1: warning: unused function 'planar_rgb9be_to_a' [-Wunused-function]
libswscale/input.c:942:5: note: expanded from macro 'rgb9plus_planar_funcs'
    rgb9plus_planar_funcs_endian(nbits, be, 1)
    ^
libswscale/input.c:929:13: note: expanded from macro 'rgb9plus_planar_funcs_endian'
static void planar_rgb##nbits##endian_name##_to_a(uint8_t *dst, const uint8_t *src[4],              \
            ^
<scratch space>:170:1: note: expanded from here
planar_rgb9be_to_a
^
libswscale/input.c:947:1: warning: unused function 'planar_rgb14le_to_a' [-Wunused-function]
rgb9plus_planar_funcs(14)
^
libswscale/input.c:941:5: note: expanded from macro 'rgb9plus_planar_funcs'
    rgb9plus_planar_funcs_endian(nbits, le, 0)  \
    ^
libswscale/input.c:929:13: note: expanded from macro 'rgb9plus_planar_funcs_endian'
static void planar_rgb##nbits##endian_name##_to_a(uint8_t *dst, const uint8_t *src[4],              \
            ^
<scratch space>:215:1: note: expanded from here
planar_rgb14le_to_a
^
libswscale/input.c:947:1: warning: unused function 'planar_rgb14be_to_a' [-Wunused-function]
libswscale/input.c:942:5: note: expanded from macro 'rgb9plus_planar_funcs'
    rgb9plus_planar_funcs_endian(nbits, be, 1)
    ^
libswscale/input.c:929:13: note: expanded from macro 'rgb9plus_planar_funcs_endian'
static void planar_rgb##nbits##endian_name##_to_a(uint8_t *dst, const uint8_t *src[4],              \
            ^
<scratch space>:224:1: note: expanded from here
planar_rgb14be_to_a
^
4 warnings generated.
libswscale/slice.c:178:56: warning: assigning to 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') from 'const uint8_t *'
      (aka 'const unsigned char *') discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                s->plane[i].line[start[i] - first + j] = src_[i] +  j * stride[i];
                                                       ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libswscale/slice.c:184:37: warning: assigning to 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') from 'const uint8_t *'
      (aka 'const unsigned char *') discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                s->plane[i].line[j] = src_[i] +  j * stride[i];
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libavcodec/libavcodec.a(hevc_mc.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libavcodec/libavcodec.a(proresdsp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libavcodec/libavcodec.a(simple_idct10.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libavcodec/libavcodec.a(hevc_mc.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libavcodec/libavcodec.a(proresdsp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libavcodec/libavcodec.a(simple_idct10.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/iPhone-i386-apple-darwin11-i386/lib/libavcodec.a(hevc_mc.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/iPhone-i386-apple-darwin11-i386/lib/libavcodec.a(proresdsp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib/iPhone-i386-apple-darwin11-i386/lib/libavcodec.a(simple_idct10.o) has no symbols
[info] Bootstraping vlc
/Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/package/ios
[info] VLCROOT = /Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc
[info] Bootstraping vlc finished
[info] >> --prefix=/Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-iPhoneSimulator/i386 --host=i386-apple-darwin11
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
configure: WARNING: No package 'dbus-1' found.
configure: WARNING: No package 'libsystemd' found.
configure: WARNING: No package 'live555' found.
configure: WARNING: Library libdc1394-2 >= 2.1.0 needed for dc1394 was not found
configure: WARNING: Library libraw1394 >= 2.0.1 libavc1394 >= 0.5.3 needed for dv1394 was not found
configure: WARNING: Library opencv > 2.0 needed for opencv was not found
configure: WARNING: Library smbclient needed for smbclient was not found
configure: WARNING: Blackmagic DeckLink SDI include files not found
configure: WARNING: Library libvncclient >= 0.9.9 needed for vnc was not found
configure: WARNING: Library freerdp >= 1.0.1 needed for freerdp was not found
configure: WARNING: No package 'libsidplay2' found (required for sid).
configure: WARNING: Library shout >= 2.1 needed for shout was not found
configure: WARNING: Library shine >= 3.0.0 needed for shine was not found
configure: WARNING: No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found. GStreamer modules will not be built.
configure: WARNING: VideoDecodeAcceleration/VDADecoder.h not found
configure: WARNING: No package 'libpostproc' found.
configure: WARNING: Library twolame needed for twolame was not found
configure: WARNING: Library libdca >= 0.0.5 needed for dca was not found
configure: WARNING: Library libmpeg2 > 0.3.2 needed for libmpeg2 was not found
configure: WARNING: Library schroedinger-1.0 >= 1.0.10 needed for schroedinger was not found
configure: WARNING: Library x265 needed for x265 was not found
configure: WARNING: Library libmfx needed for mfx was not found
configure: WARNING: Library fluidlite needed for fluidlite was not found
configure: WARNING: Library aribb24 needed for aribsub was not found
configure: WARNING: Library aribb25 >= 0.2.6 needed for aribb25 was not found
configure: WARNING: Library kate >= 0.3.0 needed for kate was not found
configure: WARNING: No package 'sdl' found.
configure: WARNING: library fontconfig not found. Styles will be disabled in freetype
configure: WARNING: sapi.h not found. Text to Speech renderer for Windows disabled
configure: WARNING: Library librsvg-2.0 >= 2.9.0 needed for svg was not found
configure: WARNING: Library librsvg-2.0 >= 2.9.0 cairo >= 1.13.1 needed for svgdec was not found
configure: WARNING: Library caca >= 0.99.beta14 needed for caca was not found
configure: WARNING: Cannot find development headers for mmal...
configure: WARNING: Library samplerate needed for samplerate was not found
configure: WARNING: Library soxr >= 0.1.2 needed for soxr was not found
configure: WARNING: Library libchromaprint >= 0.6.0 needed for chromaprint was not found
configure: WARNING: Library protobuf-lite >= 2.5.0 needed for chromecast was not found
configure: WARNING: The skins2 module depends on the Qt interface, Qt is not built so skins2 is disabled.
configure: WARNING: No package 'libvsxu' found.
configure: WARNING: Library avahi-client >= 0.6 needed for avahi was not found
configure: WARNING: Library libudev >= 142 needed for udev was not found
configure: WARNING: Library libupnp needed for upnp was not found
configure: WARNING: Library libsecret-1 >= 0.18 needed for secret was not found
[info] Building libvlc
/Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/compat/strverscmp.c:42:5: warning: 
      no previous prototype for function 'strverscmp' [-Wmissing-prototypes]
int strverscmp (const char *s1, const char *s2)
    ^
1 warning generated.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libcompat.a(dummy.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libcompat.a(tdestroy.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libcompat.a(dummy.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libcompat.a(tdestroy.o) has no symbols
video: 811 entries
audio: 255 entries
spu: 47 entries
/Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/src/misc/variables.c:340:52: warning: 
      missing field 'p_entries' initializer [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
    p_var->value_callbacks = (callback_table_t){ 0 };
                                                   ^
/Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/src/misc/variables.c:793:25: warning: 
      unused parameter 'expected_type' [-Wunused-parameter]
                    int expected_type, vlc_value_t val )
                        ^
/Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/src/misc/variables.c:852:25: warning: 
      unused parameter 'expected_type' [-Wunused-parameter]
                    int expected_type, vlc_value_t *p_val )
                        ^
/Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/src/misc/objects.c:299:36: error: 
      controlling expression type 'const struct vlc_common_members' not compatible with any generic association
      type
    vlc_object_internals_t *priv = vlc_internals(obj);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/src/misc/variables.h:53:59: note: 
      expanded from macro 'vlc_internals'
# define vlc_internals( obj ) (((vlc_object_internals_t*)(VLC_OBJECT(obj)))-1)
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/include/vlc_common.h:478:14: note: 
      expanded from macro 'VLC_OBJECT'
    _Generic((x)->obj, \
             ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [misc/objects.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
3 warnings generated.
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
[info] building universal static libs for OS style iPhone
./buildMobileVLCKit.sh: line 44: pushd: MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-iPhoneOS: No such file or directory
```

I already tried [the solution of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123399/compile-vlckit-on-mac-os-10-9) but still not working.
By not working i mean, after installing the framework, i compile a project and its failed "MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.h file not found" or :

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-iPhone/core/libcompat.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-iPhone/core/libvlc.a (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Projets/VLCKit-master-bfdcee6c3ccc7666e42091ea1b2f39903e775781/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-iPhone/core/libvlccore.a (No such file or directory)
```

Did someone success installing VLCKit ?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. Links can become broken rendering your question useless. Please consult the documentation on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the documentation on how to compile MobileVLCKit using the provided build script. It is not a matter of simply opening the project in Xcode and running it.

Additionally, since compile MobileVLCKit is not simple unless you are used to linux-style compilation systems, consider using a cocoapod.

Comment: i'm working on osx 10.10.5. and i did "./buildMobileVLCKit.sh" as it said in the documentation of MobileVLCKit in "how build framework for iOS"...

Comment: Well, appears as if the script did not succeed then. Try compiling VLCKit from the git.

Comment: i tried this : https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/3pq35k/has_anyone_managed_to_build_mobilevlckitframework/ and in terminal log, it said that all is build, but when i compile project it still not working...

Comment: Sorry, but without an output from the log, I can't provide further help.